# What does the fraction math node do?

Tags: node-editor, mathematics

I am trying to learn some procedural basics. Could you tell me what the fraction math node does? Is the result similar to modulo?

Answer (score 18):

Fract returns the fractional part of a floating-point value, as described by @Merlin, but its treatment of negative fractional parts is not actually the same as Blender's implementaion of Modulo.

If you want to see what a mathematical chunk of your shader tree is doing, it can be quite handy to make it generate a graph.

Fract:

[image]

This plane is 8x8 units, with its origin, (so (0,0)), at its center. I've added the annotations, but you can see the function without them.

Modulo 1:

[image]

Thanks to @Rich Sedman for the very useful graphing tip.

Comment: Check out page 12 in this scrapbook below. I reconstructed Rich Sedman's node tree and experimentally played around with the settings in nodes. After that, I achieved over 16 interesting different patterns.  https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/136EU3jZig2mzxIaE8MYZUWfJtQa9MkDRtchg-HXqbW4/

Comment: Merlin, it is good to know usage of each node. I previously didn't know what modulo node was for. There are not many Blenderheads who are good at mathematics. I am relearning mathematics as a hobby.

Comment: @Merlin.. Nothing wrong with your answer,  ( I UV'd it :) ) It was only after posting I remembered how often the  Blender node mod had caught me out, before I made my own group to do it, and edited the answer.. In GLSL, for example, `mod(x,1)` and `fract(x)` would be the same.. it's language dependent. A gotcha, not a bug, AFAIK.

Comment: It's good to visualize how Blender implements these, they do not always follow mathematical principle, but will favour artistic usefulness.  I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @RitaGeraghty .. some nice explorations! Recommend visiting [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/) and having a go at translating some of those into Blender nodes, if you want a real work-out! :)

Answer (score 8):

Mathematically it should return the fractional part of the number *i.e* the non whole-number part, but the blender implementation is *artistic* in it's implementation.

For **non-negative numbers** this is equivalent to using the *modulo* with a factor of **1.0**

[image: Equivalent modulo setup]

For **negative numbers** it is equivalent to using *modulo* with a factor of **-1.0**

[image: Negative numbers]

The equivalent node setup of the *fraction node* would be:

[image]