# How to make this cube texture node programmatically

Tags: texturing

Can someone give me some ideas or pictures,thanks[image]

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want so that others can help

Answer (score 4):

If you mean a procedural texture, here goes...

This tree is based on 2 node-groups:

A 'Hexagonal Grid', as discussed [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161799/35559):

[image]

Which produces a hexagonal grid of cells, each with their own UV coordinates, on the left, below:

[image]

And a 'Distance to Hexagon' group:

[image]

which takes the maximum of the shading-point's local X and its projection onto a diagonal edge, all reflected in X and Y. When put through a threshold, it produces the edges in the middle image, above. If you use the whole set-up twice, once offset by sqrt(3)/3 in Y, then you get the cube-illusion on the right.

For the hatching, the same cell-UV coordinates are used to place a *Gradient > Radial* texture in each cell of one of the overlapping hex grids, and it is stepped off into thirds with a *Snap* node, into sections valued 0, 1/3, and 2/3. (Left, below).

[image]

The values in those regions can be used to rotate a thresholded *Wave > Bands* texture, to produce the directional hatching (middle, above), and combined with the outlines to give the result (above right):

The whole tree is a bit big to show conveniently, sorry:

[image]

The result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You've just earned the *node drawer* badge

Comment: @lemon I used to emerge from my Comp. GFX. course at Uni. into a lobby, where a Matisse cut-out was hanging. After hours of brain-ache and bugs on fantastic kit, for the time, I would note what Matisse had achieved with a pair of scissors. (On his final sick-bed, what's more), And I'd think to myself: 'hang on a minute!.. something's wrong, here'...I still do.

Comment: Pretty cool result, there is something Escher-like about it, not sure if it is the rough edges. Anyway, great answer.

Comment: I love the result - it's spot on to the reference image. Really well done. I love the way you're using the same Wave texture and rotating it for each region. What's the Combine XYZ node doing? Is that left over from a previous attempt?

Comment: @RichSedman Spotted! Trust _you_ to be absolutely right! Yes it's left over from when I needed a vector somewhere, and snuk through as a value :) I'll edit, and get rid of that expensive trig. mapping earlier the branch, too. Replace with a mod. I'm sure this tree could be optimised further.