# Hexagonal Voronoi texture 2

Tags: texturing, shaders, shader-nodes, procedural, texture-coordinates

The picture below is [from a two-year-old answer about creating a hexagonal Voronoi texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/240687/82898). The [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RbH3_d9j7ro) that showed how that texture was created is no longer there. Can anyone tell me how that texture can be created in the current version of Blender?
[image: Hexagonal Voronoi texture]

Comment: I've downloaded the file and it works fine in 4.0

Comment: >> "How do I see the images in the screenshot?" --- Download the file I've mentioned. Open it. You see this. That's it :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is already a proper answer to your question on Blender.StackExchange.

Here:   =[direct_link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/240716/112570)=

The answer contains both:  explicit instructions and the blender file with a fully-set voronoi-shader.

---

This shader works perfectly on the Blender of version 4.0.2 — my screenshot :

[image: voronoi shader]

---

---

Just download this file from the bottom part of mentioned answer:

[image: download file]

---