# Bubble waffle texture

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm modelling a bubble waffle, I have to make bubbles and then wrap in a cylindrical shape but I don't know what I have to do before and after.

I tried with the displacments and UV but, I don't know why, it doesn't work.

My question is if there is a simple method to model all the waffle bubbles withous using a displacements and the bend it, I need the easiest method because I'm new to Blender

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Displacement should work just fine, what exactly is the problem? Such a shape should also be easy to model and then bend.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247691/dots-aligning-in-shading

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dots aligning in Shading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247691/dots-aligning-in-shading)

Comment: i would like to create a model 3d with bubbles without using displacements

Comment: Your title and tags seems to be misleading ...

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is real geometry without texture displacement, than you can try to ...

- start with *Extra Mes*h (add-on) > *Honeycomb*

[image]

- *Extrude* outer edges, add 6 sided *Circle* mesh and run *Knife Project* operator to cut borders
- *Extrude* and *Scale* holes, move them up and *Fill*

[image]

[image]

- add another hexagon mesh (6 sided circle) at the same size and cut with *Knife* in this folding directions
- with [**Convert to Armature**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/addam/Export-Paper-Model-from-Blender/master/object_convert_to_armature.py) add-on you can easily create rigged mesh

[image]

- add Subdivision modifier and in *Pose* mode rotate bones into desire shape

[image]

- select the Waffle object add **Surface Deform** modifier and set  *Target* your rigged hexagon (*Bind* in rest (flat) pose)

[image]

Notes:

- Since due process you will Bind-Unbind several times it is handy to keyframe rest (flat) pose like at frame zero and posed (rolled) armature pose at another frame (like 25) ... so when you have to UnBind-Bind you just go to frame zero.
- I used Armature (and not Deform modifier) to avoid stretching and ability to have better control on shape.
- [Convert to Armature](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161399/2214) example, addon is for 2.8, but works for 3.3 too.

[image]

Comment: wow bones was the good idea

Comment: Fantastic! thank you!! really helpfull