# After subvision modifier, what modifier to use to create object finish with lines?

Tags: modeling

Used a subvision modifier to extrude individual faces but I am stuck on how I would finish the surface that it subtracts lines likes this one around an object. Any advice appreciated!

[image: surface]

Answer (score 5):

Once you have any surface, you can use a Simple Deform modifier (you need to rotate an empty by 90°) to bend it into a cylinder:

[image]

However, rather than doing that, you can make a mesh line, subdivide heavily, shrinkwrap on that surface when it's flat (so you can just project down on negative Z), duplicate with an array modifier and then bend. You can control the thickness of the skin modifier by modifying the mesh line (select all, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

[image]

[image]

From there there's a lot of stuff that you can optimize - you could just overlap two UV spheres slightly, take a vertical stripe of vertices from both, and build a single mesh curve from that with minimal density for that shape - give it thickness and adjust it on the crease, duplicate with a brick-like offset, then put an array modifier on that...

Answer (score 4):

Here is a try with a *Wave Texture*, I plug it into 2 *ColorRamp* nodes, one go into the *Base Color* of a *Diffuse* or *Principled BSDF*, another one go into a *Bump*. I've unwrapped the object with the *Cylinder Projection* mode and I use the *Texture Coordinate*'s *UV* output:

[image]

Comment: This looks like biological peculiarity of the testicles to me….

Comment: I knew you'd be jealous

Comment: You just know me too well mate

Answer (score 3):

Since the silhouette isn't affected, there's a chance a simple shader solution will be enough:

[image]

[image]

Comment: i am just wondering how you could understand the question...i didn't get it ;)

Comment: @Chris I even wanted to rename the original title with "how to model a silicon ice cube maker made of vertical stripes" :D

Comment: aaaah…now I got it, what this should be….

Comment: nice, how did you model it?

Comment: @moonboots just a hex lattice, poke faces, move up, bend modifier to wrap to a circle, subdivision, something like that. I didn't show it in the answer because the way the title was renamed suggests it's the vertical stripes texture, not the entire shape, that is the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "hex lattice"?

Comment: @moonboots just a grid of hexes

Comment: oh yes ok thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's an all-GN shot at it, making use of a very similar hex-grid principle as found in [this shader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161799/35559), with a printable, manifold result.

First, A cylinder is given radial UV coordinates. Object Space: Z > Y, *Radial Gradient* > X

[image]

Then put through a cluster yielding hexagonal cells: UV per-cell, and cell-center XY, per-cell.

[image]

Anything can be mapped into the per-cell UV. In this case, it's a function of distance from 0, to give the spherical swell per cell.

The rest is beauraucracy...

- Mod 2 of face index gives the ridges: an extrusion of every other vertical stripe.
- The cell-index Y is used to exclude the flat regions above and below the cells
- An extra branch recovers the separated top of the base cylinder, and extrudes it inwards and downwards to make the inner layer.

[image]

On a second look, it probably needs a rethink to get the nice round outlines of the non-intersecting spheres, top and bottom. Probably doesn't need hexagons at all? Just a hexagonal distribution of sphere-origins?  Will get back to it..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very nice, I was thinking about exactly this, geonodes setup based on the hex shader, and also eventually figured the sharp creases in OP's example come from the shape actually being overlapping spheres in a brick-like positioning.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady  Thanks! I've got a feeling just spherical-distance-from-closest-origin might save a few nodes, as well as making it prettier?  I don't like the pointy boundary much .. :)

Comment: Yea, Geonodes makes some stuff easier, rather than calculating the center of a hex, you can just spawn hex centers, and then use Geometry Proximity node to get coordinates of the closest center and a distance to it. :)

Comment: .. @MarkusvonBroady Just what I was thinking. Expense? BVH tree? You would know about all that.... probably trivial by comparison with the rest, and shading.

Comment: I'm actually not sure, I was simply thinking that geonodes allow for easier techniques, even if considerably slower.