# How to create Fabric texture?

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]How to create this kind of texture in blender?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a procedural hexagonal weave.

There may be a more economical approach, but this seems to perform well enough. It starts with a single spoke:

[image]

.. which is a mapping of the dot-product of `(1,0,0)` in the texture-space, masked to `Y > 0`. That's grouped and used at three rotations in a higher-level group: 'Spokes':

[image]

and is also diminished by distance from `(0,0,0)`

That texture can be mapped using a tiled hexagonal UV space, as explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161799/35559). Three overlapping offset tilings are overlaid selecting the *Maximum* height at each point:

[image]

.. all grouped up into a hexagonal weave, and used to generate a bump/displacement map:

[image]

The offsets of the tilings are more 'weave like' if they are not mathematically exact, so they are left to be set by hand.

The combination gives variations on this result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I am looking for. thanks, bro

Comment: @UNIQUE MASTER in that case mark it as the good answer   ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can make these knots with the *Add Curve: Extra Objects* addon then bake the normals in order to fake the 3D relief (it's better to fake the 3D wit a normal map because a whole mesh of this kind will be rather heavy).

First create a plane, subdivide it a bit:

[image]

Create a *Curve > Knots > Celtic Links*:

[image]

Change the parameters to get the shape you want:

[image]

Comment: It's very helpful. thanks, bro

Comment: @UNIQUEMASTER If this answer helped you, you can give it an upvote or accept it, so others can find it easily. =)