# Tileable/seamless isometric render

Tags: modeling, rendering, camera

I would like to render out the middle image in the picture below, so the resulting rendered image is seamless/tileable.

[image: Blender Screenshot]

At all I would like to model a isometric cubes pattern, to finally get at least two images: a *color image* and a bump map/normal map, so I can use it as texture on other objects.

Possibly already my modelling approach was wrong, so a quick guide on how to set up the model, and how to set up the camera would be very helpful for me.

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161701/how-to-do-uv-indexing-in-hexagonal-pattern/161799#161799

Comment: note that if you're modelling it (or other), heigth/width ratio is not 1 for this pattern... so hard to make it seamless as it is