# Zooming out makes image disappear in shader

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders, image, color

I followed [Jonathan Kron's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ1WBx3kJaQ%20Jonathan%20Kron) on creating an LED-display shader. It basically multiplies together your desired image with a grid of little RGB images. It looks great when zoomed in, but when the camera / 3D view zooms out, the "lit" LEDs disappear (shader graph at the bottom):

[image: Zoomed in (red image)]
[image: Zoomed out (red image)]

I would expect that they'd still be viewable, just a little more dim. To my surprise, this problem does not happen when I change the color of the "LED image" from red to green:

[image: Zoomed in (green image)]
[image: Zoomed out (green image)]

Why does this happen? How can I keep the red color showing when the camera / 3D view zooms out?

[image: Shader graph]

Comment: Maybe due to aliasing, the LED texture at this scale becomes completely green? 

Comment: Your led-check.png image doesn't have any Texture Coordinates connected so it will default to using UVs while the other images use Generated. 
I don't see how that could cause the texture to disappear at a distance, but it was the first thing that jumped out at me from your screenshot.

Comment: Also, the keyframed Fac of the Color Mix node is a negative value, that could cause some unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @gcs_dev thanks those are both good guesses; unfortunately, fixing those does not solve the problem

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I tried playing with the values in Preferences > Viewport but unfortunately, none of them seemed to affect it.

Comment: Are the 'x' or 'check' images _themselves_ striped? My guess is somewhere, downsampling is going out of phase, sampling only the black stripes. I've made a procedural version of the screen-filter, so not using your led-rgb.png, and it's working OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may have to do with the downsampling of the filter ('led-rgb') image.. I've made a node-group which makes the '[Trinitron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinitron)' filter procedurally, instead:

[image]

- By wrapping the scaled UV space into 0-1 cycles, it produces square UV tiles, 0-1 per tile. ('in-pixel UV')
- By subtracting that from the smooth UV, we get a per-tile UV coordinate, at scale. That's scaled back down to an overall 0-1 to look up the color in the image(s). ('pixellated UV')
- The 'in-pixel UV' X generates R,G and B strips per square tile, using the color ramp
- The 'in-pixel UV' X,mod(1/3), and Y, are compared to 0 to generate black bars between the RGB strips, and the tiles. ('X Bar' and 'Y Bar')
- The X Bars, Y Bars, and RGB strips are multiplied with the image to be depicted.

With this effect:

[image]

Used with solid green and red logos, it seems to stand up to Level-of-Detail resampling OK:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works great, although "wrap" seems to be missing from my math node, so "modulo" worked alright.

Comment: Hi, @Benjamin! Thanks! Sorry, yes. That's _Vector Math > Wrap_, there in 2.8x. The only reason to use it is that it's an all-positive sawtooth, where _Modulo_ [dips into the negative](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159228/35559) with numerators below 0. 'Generated' never does, so that's OK, here.

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks! I guess we .. er.. I, have to be of a  certain age....

Comment: Throw this I in too. Huge blast from past seeing Trinitron together with  the RGB colorramp.  Wonder what the age is that the q _Who or what is Trinitron?_ rings no bells.